# Letters and numbers different heights in html5 text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Any ideas as to why the numbers and letters render at different heights? Im using Bootstrap 3.

HTML

```
<ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item">HTML5</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">CSS3</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Javascript</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">jQuery</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Github</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Bootstrap</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
#small-skills .list-group .list-group-item {
color: inherit;
border: 0.056em solid #c80a48;
background-color: inherit;
font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

See screenshot here

http://imageshack.com/a/img911/1327/yTsaIZ.png

Comment: My guess would be the font you are using. Which one is it?

Comment: That was it I was using 'Raleway' and fixed the issue when I changed it thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no markup or css changing this, it must be the actual font that is doing this. There are several ways to approach this.

1) Change the font altogether.

2) Create a font for numbers only and have this other font as the second one in the declaration:

```
font-family: numberFont, regularFont
```

3) Have a font specify the numbers you want:

```
@font-face {
   font-family: numberFont
   /*finish rest of font details here*/
   unicode-range: U+30-39
}
```

4) Add markup around each number:

```
Number <span class="number">123</span>
```

and add CSS to adjust accordingly:

```
.number {
  font-family: Arial; /* Change Font */
  position: relative;
  top: -1em; /* Adjust positioning */
}
```

Comment: so how to fix ? give css?

Comment: Added some notes on fixes.

Comment: shoose one from four method or all four steps? I try step 4 using class="number" is fail. Can any fiddle example? thanks!

Comment: You have to create CSS with .number to adjust accordingly. Either positioning, changing the font family, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Was using the font 'Raleway' changing the font fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that there are different styles of numbers. So called 'Text figures' with different heights and 'lining figures' where all numbers have height of capital letters.

I suppose in CSS you can adjsut style of numbers with `font-feature-settings` property. Try to set `"onum"` or `"lnum"` values.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Fonts/OpenType_fonts_guide#numerals_font-variant-numeric